# Convert UITableViewCell into UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

Is there a way I can convert the view of a UITableViewCell or UICollectionViewCell into an UIImageView which looks the same?

I want to be able to transform the snapshot of the cell into a UIImageView, in order to be able to animate the UIImageView. The cell itself can remain the same.

Comment: Google for UIImage from UIView, that'll get you started

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cell.bounds.size, cell.opaque, 0.0);
[cell.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *cellImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

On a retina device you should use this

```
CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, YES, scale);
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The second parameter in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` should be `NO` if the cell has transparent parts.